# Schema validation for JSON Documents

Tags: marklogic, jsonschema, marklogic-9, json-schema-validator, marklogic-dhf

I am using MarkLogic Server 9.0-6.2 with DHF version 2.0.6. The [xdmp.jsonValidate()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.jsonValidate) method is not available in this version of MarkLogic.

Can somebody please suggest how to perform schema validation for JSON documents in MarkLogic 9.0-6-2?

Comment: Have you looked at their documentation? https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.jsonValidate

Comment: Yes, I have looked into it but eventually, I got to know that it is not compatible with the version which i am using currently. Hence, I am wondering whether is it the only possible way to validate or there are some other alternative as well considering current production configuration (MarkLogic Server 9.0-6.2 with DHF version 2.0.6.)

Answer (score 1):

xdmp.jsonValidate is the best way to do it MarkLogic.

If you are on a version that doesn't support it you can use another validator. MarkLogic supports running JavaScript on the server so any JavaScript Json validator would most likely work on MarkLogic.

Here is the Javascript validator from json-schema.org https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-javascript

I had to Validate Json before MarkLogic server had xdmp.jsonValidate and we used a customer Javascript validator for that, so you could build your own.